# Specifying comma-separated command line parameters based on text file lines

Tags: bash, sed, cat, arguments, tr

I want to run a command like:

```
command argument --parameter=param1,param2,param3
```

where param1, param2, param3 may be any number of parameters coming from a file params.txt, each on one line.

I can create see a correct list of parameters with

```
echo $(cat common.modules) | tr " " ","
```

But trying

```
command argument --parameter=$(cat params.txt) | tr " " ","
```

and its obvious variants fails, probably because I can't get something like this to work:

```
echo $($(cat params.txt) | tr " " ",")
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I think you're saying your list of parameters is separated by newlines?  If so, why are you using space as the separator character in `tr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
command argument --parameter=$(tr '\n' ',' < params.txt)
```

Comment: Elegant; but perhaps without the universality of John1024's cat based solution?

Comment: @Jonathan Why less universal?

Comment: I was wondering about his comment about cat maintaining posix compatibility; I don't understand the issues involved. If yours has the same degree of universality, I'll accept it instead.

Comment: This solution is also POSIX.  (My `cat` comment was about `$(cat params.txt)` vs `$(< params.txt)`.)  My solution maintains the behavior of your original approach: it puts commas between space-separated as well as newline-separated items in `params.txt` and it does not add a trailing comma.  If those properties of your original approach, @Jonathan, are _not_ important, then this is the simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks, very clear. As those properties are not important, I'll make this the accepted answer. Your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at this command from the question:

```
command argument --parameter=$(cat params.txt) | tr " " ","
```

This runs the command `command argument --parameter=$(cat params.txt)` and pipes its output to `tr " " ","`.  That is not what you needed.

Try:

```
command argument --parameter="$(echo $(cat params.txt) | tr " " "," )"
```

Here, `echo $(cat params.txt)` causes word splitting to be done on the contents of `params.txt`.  This results in all the parameters being space-separated.  Then, `tr " " ","` replaces the spaces with commas.

Note that by using `cat` in the above  we maintain POSIX compatibility.  This means, for example, that this command will work under the default shell, `/bin/sh`, on Ubuntu and Debian and similar systems.